# 21:9 5k2k monitor recommendation

Tags: monitors

I have and old 29" 21:9 monitor that needs replacement. I love the the form factor. It's used primarily for coding, and sometimes for gaming. So the most important part is resolution, I was thinking of 5k2k. Good refresh rate would be nice, but I guess the resolution is more important for me.

After searching for a while it seems like there is not that much of a choice in this category and most of them are not in stock in my area:

- LG UltraWide 34WK95U-W
- MSI Prestige PS341WU

So the requirements are:

- good resolution (5k2k?)
- > 29"
- price ~1k$
- good refresh rate would be nice but not required

Can you please recommend some other good options I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

I found this model of monitor, I think it is to your liking.
Model: AOC Agon AG352UCG6 Black Edition

**Screen size: 35-inch 
Frame-Rate: 120Hz
 Aspect ratio: 21: 9 
 Resolution: 3,440 x 1,440 
 Brightness: 300 cd / m2 
 Refresh rate: 120Hz 
 Response time: 4ms 
 Viewing angle: 178/178 
 Contrast ratio: 2,500: 1: 
 Color support: sRGB 100%**

[Amazon Price $599.99](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LCX18MW)